# Windows 10 STOP error after Hibernation and Fast Boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I've noticed that recently my Windows 10 Pro computer will BSOD upon startup, but only after a Hybrid / "Fast" Shutdown, or Hibernation. It will also bluescreen after being woken from Hybrid Sleep if the power was lost (Booting from machine state). The bluescreen messages are always memory related too, such as "IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL", Etc.

This has led me to believe that my computer is having issues restoring the machine state from the disk. Of course I could disable Hybrid Sleep / Shutdown and Hibernation, but I use those features on a daily basis. If anyone else has had this or a similar issue and has found a fix, it would be greatly appreciated.

**System Specs:**

```
Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit
Intel Core 2 Quad Q9300 @ 2.50GHz
8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 332MHz
EVGA GTX 750 Ti

Disks:
465GB Seagate ST3500620AS
465GB Western Digital WDC WD5000AAKX-00ERMA0
596GB Western Digital WDC WD6400AAKS-22A7B0 **(Main C:\ Drive)**
```

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump (up load a zip of this folder to onedrive and post a share link here)

Comment: The minidump folder is completely empty for some strange reason.

Comment: have you disabled the pagefile? Widows needs a pagefile to create dumps

Comment: Didn't disable it, but I have moved it to a different drive just today. Perhaps the pagefile wasn't functioning correctly and that's why the issues are occuring in the first place?

Comment: maybe. try to set the pagefile on drive C

Answer (score 0):

Seems it wasn't an error with my drives or Windows install. A motherboard replacement fixed the issue. Sorry to anyone else who may have had the same or similar issues.